# Sharing enums across services angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, enums

I have an enum in one of my services.

```
home.factory('myService', ['$dialogs', '$resource', 
function ($dialogs, $resource) {
    var myEnum= {
        val1: 0,
        val2: 1
    };
    return {
        DoSomething : function (param1) {
            ...
        }
    };
}]);
```

I need to share this enum when I call a method in some other service.
Basically need to send the enum as a parameter to some other method in another service.
What is the best approach to do so ?

Comment: return enum from your factory

Comment: Angular has [constants](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#constant) , which you can inject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a `constant`:

```
app.constant('myEnum', {
    val1: 0,
    val2: 1
});
```

And inject it to other services:

```
app.service('myService', ['myEnum', function (myEnum) {
    console.log(myEnum);
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

return enum from your factory

```
home.factory('myService', ['$dialogs', '$resource', ,
function ($dialogs, $resource) {

        return {
                 DoSomething : function (param1){
                 },

                 myEnum: {
                    val1: 0,
                    val2: 1
                 }

          };
   };
}]);
```

you can access by

```
myService.myEnum;
```